# How to make a smooth curve/rotate in a CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a CSS animation to make a plane take off from a runway and then make a slight curve to the right as it gains altitude. To accomplish this, I believe I need to adjust scale, rotation and x/y coordinates in the keyframes. I've been playing around with it for a while but I can't figure out how to make it look natural. What's the best way to calculate the various values I will need to make a smooth curve up and to the right?

```css
.container {
  width:700px;
  height:100%;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
}

.airplane {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    animation: takeoff linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes takeoff {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0);
    }
    5% {
        transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0) scale(.9);
    }
    10% {
        transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0) scale(.9);
    }
    20% {
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(0) scale(0.85);
    }
    30% {
       transform:translate(0,0) rotate(0) scale(0.80);
    }
    40% {
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(0) scale(0.75);
    }
    50% {
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(5deg) scale(0.5);
    }
    60% {
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(5deg) scale(0.45);
    }
    70% {
        transform: translate(150px, -200px) rotate(10deg) scale(.4);
    }
    80% {
        transform:translate(200px,-300px) rotate(20deg) scale(0.35);
    }
    90% {
        transform:translate(250px,-400px) rotate(30deg) scale(0.3);
    }
    100% {
        transform:translate(300px,-500px) rotate(30deg) scale(0.3);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="airplane" src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhHSc.png" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably consider an animation on the container to make it easier to handle:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: takeoff-alt ease-in 1s 1s forwards;
}
img {
 max-width:100%;
}

.airplane {
  animation: takeoff linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes takeoff {
  to {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
}

@keyframes takeoff-alt {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(30deg) translateY(-100%);
  }
}

body {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="airplane" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhHSc.png" />
</div>
```